# Save Edittext in Array

Tags: android, arrays, matrix, android-edittext

Hi I want to save the number of the Edittexts in a 2d Array

But when i try this my app always crashes.

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int gridchilds = grid.getChildCount();
    int [][] MatrixArray = new int[zeilen][spalten];
    // ITERATE THROUGH EACH CHILDS

    for(int i = 0; i < gridchilds; i++)
    {
        ViewGroup gridChild = (ViewGroup) grid.getChildAt(i);
        int childSize = gridChild.getChildCount();
        for(int k = 0; k < childSize; k++)
        {
            if( gridChild.getChildAt(k) instanceof EditText)
            {
                MatrixArray[i][k]=  Integer.parseInt(((EditText) gridChild.getChildAt(k)).getText().toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

But if I change This

```
MatrixArray[i][k]=  Integer.parseInt(((EditText) gridChild.getChildAt(k)).getText().toString());
```

to this:

```
MatrixArray[0][0]=  Integer.parseInt(((EditText) gridChild.getChildAt(k)).getText().toString());
```

It works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what `error` you getting? can you post that?

Comment: Guess it's index out of bound exception. `zeilen` should be equal or greater than `gridchilds` and `spalten` should be equal or greater than `childSize`.

Comment: @kdblue where can I see what Error was created? Sry Im new to Android

Comment: it seems like `childSize` and/or `gridchilds` greater than `zeilen` `spalten`

Comment: @Warlord, you can check that https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Comment: @MeowCat2012 and yes that was the Problem thanks :)